# GKE Alerts using Alerting Policy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

We have a GKE cluster, in which we have enabled Cloud Monitoring.

**Trying to Achieve:**

1. Add alerts on GKE Node Up/Down
2. Alerts on CPU and Memory Utilisation
3. Alerts on Disk Utilisation

**Issue:**
We tried to setup alerts with pod/volume/utilization for disk and node/cpu/allocatable_utilization.
But all these metrics are not in percentage.

We checked GKE dashboard in Cloud Monitoring, it contains all the necessary metrics visualised in percentages. Is there a way to setup alerts based on this dashboard?

Comment: "yes, there is a way". But what exactly is your question ? If you see dashboard, just create an alert from it by adding condition. Or convert dashboard code to MQL, and make MQL based alert.

Comment: @c69 How to convert dashboard to MQL?
I was unable to create alert for GKE. The default dashboard for GKE doesn't have an option to do that

Comment: edit your dashboard, then switch to MQL. See: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/query-editor , ps: i don't know/remember if default GKE dashboard is editable (had not been using GCP for a while)

Comment: also, maybe this link is more helpful https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/query-editor#ql-query-conversion

Comment: Yeah @c69 GKE dashboard is uneditable. As of now I went with their default metrics which provides metrics in fractions. Will eventually shift to prometheus+grafana+alertmanager if we don't find this reliable. Also I am already familiar with PromQL